# App rejected due to "AWS credential leaks"

Tags: android, amazon-s3

Our need is to upoad the file to s3. First we have hardcoded the aws key in strings.xml. our app is rejected from play store due to aws credentials leak. So we sorted out this problem by removing aws key from local and passed from API. That is also not helps. still playstore was rejecting the build. Then we did upload the image by using aws cognito jwt token and removed the usage of AWS(access key ID and secret access key) from our code. But still google is rejecting our app.but we are uploading new build with version 3.0 but the google rejecting our application and saying that our old version 2.0 is leaking credential. i am not sure the problem is from our side/ google is using my old build for verification. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Best practice is to have your API generate a pre-signed link for uploading the files to S3 and send that to the client.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am having the same issue

Comment: anyone got  solution ?